# How can I do 3000+ damage in Wrestle Jump?

Tags: wrestle-jump

There's an achievement in the iOS version for getting at least 3000 damage, is it only achievable under certain conditions or will I get it eventually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been watching replays at Everyplay and it seems quite random, it looks like having wind and/or ice modifiers makes it a little easier.

[Replay with ice](https://everyplay.com/player?id=29632)

[Replay with wind](https://everyplay.com/player?id=139583)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get 3047 on the long hill level with 5 wind in the direction of the hill. You just need to get the characters spinning, and aimed correctly will give you 2000+ every time.